# no such window: window was already closed issue in selenium webdriver with javascript, even though the window is not closed

Tags: javascript, selenium

I have a script that buys an article from a web-based shop. After placing an order I receive a confirmation (Thank you message) on the web page. when I try to verify this message using Assert statement then I get the error: *no such window: window was already closed*.[Screen shot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xNXZ4.png)

I have tried finding window handle names and they do not change from the previous steps. TIA for any help or suggestions.

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: no such window: target window already closed
from unknown error: web view not found
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.130)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18362 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 9 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'ADMIN', ip: '192.168.1.xxx', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb), userDataDir=C:\Users\Comp-7\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir10912_1737}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, hasTouchScreen=false, version=79.0.3945.130, platform=XP, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, locationContextEnabled=true, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=}]
Session ID: 74ea091bd6b37000346511c33ea55755

Comment: Can you please add your code in question?

Comment: Dont paste screenshots, add your errors in this question itself. Also add your code for others to verify and help you better.

Comment: Assert.assertTrue(generalPage.textOrderConfirmation().getText().contains("Glückwunsch"));
 just getting the text froma box and comparing if it contains a certain word.

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: no such window: target window already closed
from unknown error: web view not found
  (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.130)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18362 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 9 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.4.0', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'ADMIN', ip: '192.168.1.xxx', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.

Comment: System.out.println("=============================="+driver.getWindowHandles());
  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

  payPalPage.buttonPaypalPaymentConfirmation().click();
  System.out.println("=============================="+driver.getWindowHandles());
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
if(browserName.equals("safari")) {Thread.sleep(12000);}
  System.out.println("=============================="+driver.getWindowHandles());  Assert.assertTrue(generalPage.textOrderConfirmation().getText().contains("Glückwunsch"));

all get window handles give me the same result, no change in ids.

Comment: any chance that thiw "window" is actually an `iframe`?

Comment: There is an iframe on the page (as a pop up). What could i do next? The element that I am verifying is on the main page.

Comment: I found a workaround. I save the window handle name to a variable at the start of the script and then forcibly switched to it before doing the actual comparison of the text at the end of the script. though, I am still curious about why I was getting the error.